# Node.JS Vash TypeError: while rendering template object is not a function

Tags: node.js, vash

There is another thread that covers this, but I am not allowed to post to it. Also, the only answer does not seem to solve my problem.

I am getting the Object not a function error when using the @html.extend() method.  I have read all of the very limited threads on this topic.  They all say the same thing. That I need to ensure the path is correct to the layout.vash file I am extending. My declaration looks like this in the file that I want to want to extend with my layout.vash file.

```
@html.extend('layout', function (model) {

     .... do stuff ...

})
```

What is odd, is that some pages work fine others don't.  The path is correct. I am sure of this because of the fact the files in the same director exhibit different behavior.

Does anyone know what other mistake I could be making to cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, vash was unable to parse the content within  ...

I pulled it out from the layout page and created a separate .css file, and the annoying "object is not a function" error disappeared.

I speculate that vash collides with some css syntax.
For you info, my style statements that caused the trouble were these.

```
  <style type="text/css">
  *{padding:0;margin:0;}
  html{border-top:10px #1abf89 solid;}
  body{width:800px;margin:0 auto;padding:5% 20px 20px;font-family:Palatino, Optima, Georgia, serif;}
  @media all and (max-width:1024px){ body, pre a{width:60%;} }
  small{color:#999;}
  #toolbar{margin-bottom:1em;position:fixed;left:20px;margin-top:5px;}
  #toolbar [class^="icon-"]:before, #toolbar [class*=" icon-"]:before{font-family:'pen'}
  #mode{color:#1abf89;;cursor:pointer;}
  #mode.disabled{color:#666;}
  #mode:before{content: '\e813';}
  #hinted{color:#1abf89;cursor:pointer;}
  #hinted.disabled{color:#666;}
  #hinted:before{content: '\e816';}

  #fork{position:fixed;right:0;top:0;}

  /*
  When the webpage is printed
  this media query hides extra elements,
  and makes the text content fit the page.
  */
  @media print {
    #fork, #toolbar {
        display: none;
    }
    body {
        width: 94%;
        padding-top: 1em;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    html {
        border-top: 0;
    }
  }
  </style>
```

Comment: Just looking at this all these months later. ;) I think your issue was that the @ signs need to be escaped.  For Vash the @ sign has a very significant meaning. Without escaping it Vash will try to compile what follows.